# How could extract context from a p-tag with selected option and also others word have no option to selecte?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a p-tag for showing the article which contains two types -
words you don't need to change and words you can select in it. E.G.[image: 1]

```
    <div class="context">
        <p v-html="report_data" class="showTxt" id="showTxt" contenteditable="true"></p>
    </div>
```

and I wanna make a window for showing the result which user selected and also include others don't need to change.

**
rr = $('#showTxt option:selected').text()

this way would delect other word don't need to change

r_content = document.getElementById('showTxt').textContent

and this way would show everything include all option

thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually looking for? Please clearly describe the expected output/requirement

Comment: I want a string output like(from the picture example):
"I remember when I first arrived in the United States. Just before"

in this case, you select Just for instead Even, and I want get the result for whole sentence

Comment: Please add a correct code snippet where the issue is reproducible.

Comment: I make the string contain html tag from the Flask(my backend), and just throw it to report_data, original report data like that： <p>United States. <select style="padding: 0px; background:#edf2ff;"><option>Even</option><option>Just</option></select>before <select style="padding: 0px; background:#edf2ff;"></select>。 then just use v-html to show it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me, but I guess you want to get the text user selected. If so you can use [`getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).

```js
window.getSelection().toString();
```